# docker push to private registry - An image does not exist locally with the tag: localhost:5000/xxxx

Tags: server, docker

I have running private registry

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart always --name registry registry:2
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS       PORTS                                       NAMES
1707fb042a43   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   4 days ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

I have image need to push to my private registry

```
sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
coinbase                               latest    7bfb7cc3d51c   11 months ago   781MB
```

When I try to push my image to my private registry

```
sudo docker push localhost:5000/coinbase:latest
```

docker answer me:

```
The push refers to repository [localhost:5000/coinbase]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: localhost:5000/coinbase
```

Why? It looks as don't understanding that localhost:5000 is URL of my private registry. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tag your image with registry host included

```
docker image tag coinbase:latest localhost:5000/coinbase:latest
```

Check [docker push documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) for details and examples.